# preg replace to give title from url

Tags: php

i have this code which renders database entry into images without any issue but i want to trim the alt value as it shows complete url. i want to show string after last slash without extension in alt value. here is my code

```
function decode_bb($msg){
$search_array = array(
"/\[img]([^'\"\?\&]*(\.gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp))\[\/img]/iU");

$replace_array = array(

" <img src=\"\\1\" alt=\"\\1\"/> "

);

$msg = preg_replace($search_array, $replace_array, $msg);
return $msg;
}


$text='style_Forever 21 [img]http://cdn9.lbstatic.nu/files/looks/medium/2013/08/15/3225332_IMG_20130810_2.jpg[/img][img]http://cdn11.lbstatic.nu/files/looks/medium/2013/08/15/3225294_1000340_10201946229836897_118758683_n.jpg[/img]';
    echo nl2br(decode_bb($text));
```

output is

```
 style_Forever 21  <img src="http://cdn9.lbstatic.nu/files/looks/medium/2013/08/15/3225332_IMG_20130810_2.jpg" alt="http://cdn9.lbstatic.nu/files/looks/medium/2013/08/15/3225332_IMG_20130810_2.jpg"/>  <img src="http://cdn11.lbstatic.nu/files/looks/medium/2013/08/15/3225294_1000340_10201946229836897_118758683_n.jpg" alt="http://cdn11.lbstatic.nu/files/looks/medium/2013/08/15/3225294_1000340_10201946229836897_118758683_n.jpg"/>
```

in alt value i want to display only 3225332_IMG_20130810_2 and 3225294_1000340_10201946229836897_118758683_n etc as it has some meaning. not full url.

it can be done with explode easily but how to use explode here i tried

```
 $c3=explode("/","\\1");  $city3=end($c3);
```

but it is not working

Comment: Capture it separately: `([^'\"&?]*?(/[^'\"&?/]*\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|bmp)))` and you'll be able to use `$1` and `$2` for "full URL" and "last piece" respectively.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol not working

Comment: [Yes working](https://regex101.com/r/s1oncj/1)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol please give as answer . its working ,thanksssssss